# WMS Compact Cached Service NOT Drawing?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, wms, cache, arcgis-10.3

I have two services, one a compact cached service the other an exploded cached service. Both are from the same data source, have the same publishing parameters (minus compact/exploded), and were published via ArcGIS Server 10.3.

In ArcMap, I make a WMS connection, add the exploded cached WMS service. It works fine.

Problem: I make a WMS connection, add the compact cached WMS service. The layer fails to draw, and eventually times out. In my ArcGIS Server manager log I get the following error:

[image]

I have tested a few things, and this is what I know:

- The data frame default setting in ArcMap for WMS is EPSG: 4326, when you bring the service in
- For the compact cached service, if I change the data frame to EPSG: 3857 the service draws
- For the compact cached service, the service does NOT draw at EPSG: 4326, the default data frame setting
- For the exploded cached service, the service draws if the data frame is in either EPSG: 4326 or 3857
- I have tried to add EPSG: 4326 in the ArcGIS Server Administrator Directory > Edit Map Server > Service Properties, this did NOT work
- The 'unspecified error' is not enough information to help
- I do not get his issue if published via ArcGIS Server 10.2.2 (but I need to use 10.3)